# Working with two network adapters on windows7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, virtual-machine, network-adapter

I have two network adapters on the same computer. I want one network adapter to work only with one program (VMWARE) and the other to work for everything else.

Is this possible? If require, I can do some coding, but I have no idea were to start.

Comment: why downvote with no comment?

Comment: Because your question is not clear.  You can read the documentation on the VM application to learn how to do this.

Comment: @Ramhound that is not really related to VMware. the compuer routs all my communications throught one network adapter, and I want to use another and me been ubclear is a reason to leave a comment, and not to downvote.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to go to the install directory of the VMWARE Workstation folder,
usually it is in: C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\
run the exe file: vmnetcfg.exe

then disable automatic bridging in vmnetcfg.exe and then assign vmnet0 to physical nic#2.
then on the host disable all protocols but the vmware-bridge protocol for physical nic #2

Comment: I am using VMPLayer. not such exe there :(

Comment: Maybe you should have included that in the question?

Comment: if you are using vmplayer, you need to edit the .vmx file using notepad or wordpad, check for the ethernet0.connectionType and ethernet1.connectionType, it should be either: "bridged" or "NAT" , try changing ethernet0 and ethernet1 fields to "custom", as ethernet0.connectionType=custom    & ethernet1.connectionType="custom"